# How to replace list of elements to a list of elements as individual elements

Tags: arrays, wolfram-mathematica

I have 2 arrays of elements

`{x,y,z}, {1,2,3}`

and formula

`x^2 + y^2 + z^3+x*z`

I need to make an replacement rule which would replace similar to the rule

`{x->1,y->2,z->3}`

using this input lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Study https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Thread.html and look carefully at the examples shown.

Then try

```
rules=Thread[Rule[{x,y,z},{1,2,3}]]
```

and see if that gives you

```
{x->1,y->2,z->3}
```

and then if

```
x^2 + y^2 + z^3+x*z/.rules
```

does the substitution you are looking for

Comment: It was much simpler then I expected. I tried to make a designated function.